# How to get this object as the result

Tags: javascript

in JavaScript I declared this `var a = "p", b = "q", c = "r";`

and  `var obj = {a : "x", b: "y", c:"z"};`

and I want `var obj = { "p": "x" , "q": "y", "r": "z"}`

but I am not getting the same.

Comment: use subscripts `obj[a] = "x";`

Comment: Show us your code. Have you tried `var obj2 = {[a]: obj[a], `…`};`?

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj = {};
obj[a] = "x"; // is what you want.
//Or
obj = {[a]: "x"}
```

variables cannot be evaluated for keys unless you directly point to it like above.

```
var obj = {a: "x"}; // evaluates the a as a string key name of 'a'
```

Comment: @Xufox Added that :)

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) like this:

```
var obj = {[a]: "x", [b]: "y", [c]: "z"}
```

or you can use `obj[a]` as other's have suggested which means use the value in `a` as the name of the key.

**Note:** computed properties won't have support in every environment. See the "Browser Compatibility" section in the link I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Look：

```js
var a = "p", b = "q", c = "r";
var obj = {[a] : "x", [b]: "y", [c]:"z"};

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Code

```
var a = "p", b = "q", c = "r";
var obj = {a : "x", b: "y", c:"z"};

function getObj(obj){
   var scope = this;
   var result = {};
   for(var key in obj){
      result[eval(key)] = obj[key];
   }
   return result;
};
var requiredObj = getObj(obj); 

//result - Object {p: "x", q: "y", r: "z"}
console.log(requiredObj);
```